# アニメーション途中の座標の取得の方法がわかりません。考え方などでも教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3

現在勉強なども含めてやったことがないことに挑戦しようと課題(こんなアプリを作る)を決めてアプリ制作をしています。(今回は妖精が飛び交うようなアプリにしようと思っています。)

今回アプリの中でタイマーで動かしているアニメーションの座標またはタグを取得してタッチしたものがそうであれば成功のアラート違えば違うアラートを出したいと考えています。

しかし。タッチした時のタッチした場所の座標の取得などはできたり、もともとのviewがタッチしたところからどれだけ離れているかなどはわかるのですが、移動最中のviewのリアルタイムの座標の取得方法が全くわかりません。

現在までにできているのはランダムに移動した後のviewの座標の更新(あくまで設定した座標なので移動中とか全く関係なくなってしまいます。)ぐらいです。

何か、いい方法やヒントなどあればご教授お願いします。

ちなみに、コードはswift3で以下のような形で書いています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let FairyView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        FairyView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        FairyView.frame.size.height = 130
        FairyView.frame.size.width = 130
        FairyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        let sampleX = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.width)))
        let sampley = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.height)))
        FairyView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(sampleX)
        FairyView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(sampley)
        self.view.addSubview(FairyView)
        FairyView.tag = 1

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.createFairy), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: UITouch in touches {

        let tag = touch.view!.tag
        if (tag == 1) {

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "成功"
            alert.message = "次"
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Ok")
            alert.show()


        }else{

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "失敗"
            alert.message = "ゲームオーバー！"
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Ok")
            alert.show()

        }
    }
}



func createFairy(){

    let sampleXx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.width)))
    let sampleyy = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.size.height)))
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.toValue = [sampleXx, sampleyy]
    animation.duration = 2.0
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
    animation.autoreverses = true
    view.viewWithTag(1)?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:sampleXx , y:sampleyy)
    view.viewWithTag(1)?.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    view.viewWithTag(1)?.setNeedsDisplay()


}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

アニメーション中の`UIView`（のサブクラス）の位置情報（`center`、`frame`など）は、アニメション終了時の位置情報になります。そのままでは、移動中の位置情報は得られません。それを知るには、`CALayer`クラスのメソッド`presentation()`によって、“見かけ”のレイヤーオブジェクトを取得し、それの位置情報を取得するという方法をとります。
以下、サンプルコードを示します。メソッド`startAnimation()`は、`UIViewController`のサブクラスのメソッドで、`targetView`をアニメーションさせるとともに、タイマーを使って、その位置情報を`print`します。

```
func startAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0){
        self.targetView.center = CGPoint(x: self.targetView.center.x, y: self.targetView.center.y - 200.0)
    }
    var counter = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true){timer in
        if let position = self.targetView.layer.presentation()?.position {
            print(position)
        }
        counter += 1
        if counter > 9 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

`presentation()`メソッドの返り値がオプショナルである点をお忘れなく。

Comment: 回答早くにありがとうございます！！とても嬉しいです。早速やってみようと思います。スタックオーバーフローに登録するのに勇気が行ったのでうが、回答してもらえたことで登録してよかったと強く思いました。サンプルコードもありがとうございます！！(>ω<)✨

Comment: せっかく教えていただいたのですが、実装できても二回目通るとエラーになってしまいます。簡単でもいいのでこれを使っているプロジェクトなどあれば教えていただきたいです。githubで探して見たのですが、なかなか見つからなくて…

Comment: 私は、メソッド`presentation()`を紹介しただけの立場なので、それ以上の依頼は、私の任ではありません。「これを使っているプロ‌​ジェクト」を探すより、新規に質問をたて、「二回目通るとエラーに」なる、質問者さんが書いたコードを提示して、不備な点を指摘してもらう方が、効率的だと、私は思います。

Comment: ありがとうございますo(▽`)o=з=зまた整理して新規に質問たててみます⭐️

Comment: やはりもう少し自分で考えながら行って見ようと思ってました。その結果、自分がしたい方法ができる方法ではなかったみたいでした。その部分のコードをこの方法に習ったらできたので、そこらへんの調節を行ってみようと考えています。本当にありがとうございました。教えてもらわなかったらここから進まなかったと思おうので本当に助かりました。知識不足で至らない点がたくさんありますが、質問をたてて見たりのアドバイスや、コードのサンプルまでありがとうございました。正直今思うとここまでしてくださったのに行動が遅い自分が情けないです。なので、頑張って成長しようとおもいます。本当にありがとうございました。！！⭐️